# Dual boot 2 Android-86 based distro (Bliss OS and PrimeOS)

Tags: boot, grub, android-x86

I try to make a dual boot Bliss OS/Prime OS, but whatever I do, there is always only one entry in the boot menu, it's Prime.

What I did:

I tried to install Bliss OS first, then install Prime OS on its dedicated partition = only Prime OS is mentioned in the boot menu, impossible to boot on Bliss.

I tried to reinstall Bliss from the live CD = same thing.

I redid it from the beginning, erased everything (formatting) and installed this time Prime OS, and then, Bliss OS. = same thing.

I installed a linux distro, and from it, I edited the grub (Installed on the disc, as I had missing files problems in the live session) = same thing.

It seems that the 2 OS are considered only one. So, what is the configuration to have each one of them mentioned in the boot menu, and of course, bootable?

They work like a charm alone, but I can't install them side by side.

This is my grub config for PrimeOS (in grub-customizer):

```
insmod part_gpt
set root='hd0,msdos6'
search --file --no-floppy --set=root /PrimeOS/system.sfs
linux /PrimeOS/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug SRC=/primeos
initrd /PrimeOS/initrd.img
```

And for Bliss:

```
insmod part_gpt
set root='hd0,msdos5'
search --file --no-floppy --set=root /PrimeOS/system.sfs
linux /Bliss/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug SRC=/primeos
initrd /Bliss/initrd.img
```

I've checked that "Bliss" and "PrimeOS" are the real names of the folders I get in the root of the partition.

I'm not sure this config is well written, but I cannot understand why installing them one after the other, as I did for each of my OS, doesn't work.